# Please help me in factorising this equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

$\ y^2-8xy+17x^2-4y+4=0 $

I have been trying to solve this factorisation but I am unable to reach the correct conclusion to this. Help on this would be highly appreciated.Thanks in advance

Comment: $(y-4x)^2+x^2+(y-2)^2$

Comment: I don't think it can be factored. What is this correct conclusion that you are trying to reach?

Comment: From my factorisation you can therefore conclude that $\nexists x,y\in R$ that satisfying the above equation

Comment: $\ y^2-8xy+17x^2-4y+4=0 $.The question is modified . Please answer it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $\ 2y^2-8xy+17x^2-4y+4=0$ is quadratic in $y$, in particular if we rewrite the equation as $$2y^{2} - (8x+4)y + 17x^{2}+4 = 0$$ we see that the equation is in the form $ay^{2}+by+c=0$ where $a = 2, b = -(8x+4),$ and $c = 17x^{2}+4$.  Applying the quadratic formula gives us
\begin{align*}
y &= \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^{2}-4ac}}{2a}\\
&=\frac{8x+4\pm\sqrt{(8x+4)^{2}-4(2)(17x^{2}+4)}}{4}\\
&=\frac{8x+4\pm\sqrt{64x^{2}+64x+16-136x^{2}-32}}{4}\\
&=\frac{8x+4\pm\sqrt{-72x^{2}+64x-16}}{4}\\
&=\frac{8x+4\pm\sqrt{8(-9x^{2}+8x-2)}}{4}\\
&=\frac{8x+4\pm2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{-9x^{2}+8x-2}}{4}\\&=\frac{1}{2}\left(4x+2\pm\sqrt{2}\sqrt{-9x^{2}+8x-2}\right).
\end{align*}
This means that the equation can be factored as
$$\left(y - \frac{1}{2}\left(4x+2+\sqrt{2}\sqrt{-9x^{2}+8x-2}\right)\right)\left(y-\frac{1}{2}\left(4x+2-\sqrt{2}\sqrt{-9x^{2}+8x-2}\right)\right)=0$$

If you instead think of the equation as a quadratic in $x$ you would get a similar result in the form $(x-r)(x-s) = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

one possibility is
$$\left(y-\frac{1}{2}\left(2+4x-\sqrt{2}\sqrt{-9x^2+8x-2}\right)\right)\left(y-\frac{1}{2}\left(2+4x+\sqrt{2}\sqrt{-9x^2+8x-2}\right)\right)$$

Comment: how did u do it.Please show the steps

Comment: i have solved your equation for $y$ as a quadratic equation

Comment: and can you tell me WHY? this is a factorization, or not? the question was "Please help in factorising this equation"and this was exactly what i have done!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Observe that when $x\in{\mathbb R}$, one has $-9 x^2+8 x -2 < 0$. So it must be a complex factorization.

Comment: yes ok, one fact is that there is a $\pm$ sign and it is easy and we can write $i$ before the square root

Comment: It seems that the set of solutions is an "imaginary ellipse". See the wikipedia article on matrix representation of conic sections :)

Comment: oh a nice case was found

Answer (score 0):

Assume that it could be factored. Then, by degree reasons,
$$
2y^2-8xy+17x^2-4y+4=(ax+by+c)(dx+ey+f)
$$
This says that $ad=17$, $be=2$, $cf=4$ etc. We see that there is no solution in integers $a,b,c,d,e,f$. The same is true for
$$
y^2-8xy+17x^2-4y+4.
$$
But it can decomposed (not factored) as $(y-2)^2+(17x - 8y)x$.

Comment: question modified.PLease factorise it now.

Comment: @BhargabKakati Again you cannot factor it in two linear factors.